# Apache Module mod_proxy_balancer

Tags: apache-2.2, load-balancing

I'm new in apache balancing stuff.

I'm reading the docs in [link text](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_proxy_balancer.html)

```
<Proxy balancer://mycluster >
    BalancerMember http://192.168.1.50:80
    BalancerMember http://192.168.1.51:80
</Proxy>

ProxyPass /test balancer://mycluster/
```

1. to start where do I put the above configuration (I mean, in wich file, vhost? httpd.conf?):
2. How do make it work?

Thanks,
Pedro

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you put it in your vhost configuration. as below:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  <Proxy balancer://lb>
     BalancerMember http://10.14.10.250 timeout=10s 
     BalancerMember http://10.14.10.251 timeout=10s 
  </Proxy>
  ProxyPass /lb/ balancer://lb

  <Proxy balancer://fo>
     BalancerMember http://10.14.10.250 timeout=10s 
     BalancerMember http://10.14.10.251 timeout=10s status=+H
  </Proxy>
  ProxyPass /fo/ balancer://fo
</VirtualHost>
```

first one is for 50-50 load balancer, second one - one dedicated master [ preferred server ], another - hot standby to which requests are sent only when master is down.

Comment: I put that, but no redirections aways the same address, I restart apache without errors! any thing I should do more?

Comment: @pcamacho - i assume you have necessary modules loaded.. mod_proxy_balancer.so, mod_proxy.so, mod_proxy_http.so. make sure it's not your browser's cache playing tricks on you - disable/clean it.